# Custom markup parser not processing newlines

Tags: c#, .net, parsing

I have been creating a custom markup parser to use in my application.
It works flawlessly unless the opening and closing tags are on separate lines.

Example:

```
<test>This is a test</test>
```

works perfectly, but

```
<test>
    this
    is
    a
    test
</test>
```

returns a blank string.

My current workaround is to use `[-n]` as newline characters in the string and programmatically replace it with `\n\r`.  This, however is very inconvenient.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace AsysEditor.Classes
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Contains the methods needed to parse a simple XML file
    /// </summary>
    class XMLParser
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Parses a simple XML file.
        /// </summary>
        /// <remarks>
        /// Does NOT support nested tags.
        /// </remarks>
        /// <param name="xml">The file to parse</param>
        /// <param name="tag">The wanted value</param>
        /// <param name="clean">Remove whitespace</param>
        /// <param name="replaceNewLines">Replace "[-n]" with "\n\r"</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static string Parse(string xml, string tag, bool clean, bool replaceNewLines)
        {
            if (xml == String.Empty || tag == String.Empty) { return "error"; }
            if (!(xml.Contains("<" + tag + ">"))) { return "error"; }

            // Get all XML tags: <tag>
            string _tag = "\\<(.*?)\\>";
            MatchCollection tagMatches = new Regex(_tag).Matches(xml);

            List<string> tags = new List<string>();

            // Add the tag to a list
            foreach (Match m in tagMatches)
            {
                // Clean the tag and add it to the list
                tags.Add(m.Groups[1].Value.Replace("<", string.Empty).Replace(">", string.Empty));
            }

            // Get the value of the tag
            foreach (string h in tags)
            {
                if (!h.Equals(tag)) continue;

                string head = "\\<" + h + "\\>";
                string foot = "\\</" + h + "\\>";

                string contents = new Regex(head + "(.*?)" + foot).Match(xml).Groups[1].Value;

                // Clean the result if nessesary
                if (clean) return contents.Trim();
                else if (replaceNewLines) return contents = Regex.Replace(contents, "\\[-n\\]", "\r\n");
                else return contents;
            }

            return "error";
        }

    }
}
```

<sup>(If it's doing a lot of unnecessary things, its because I'm planing on extending functionality later)</sup>

If someone could explain where I am going wrong here, it would be very helpful.

[(Also, the entire project is on GitHub)](https://github.com/Criticaldiamonds/asys/commit/fe6da85835e6eea215a45c4ec24ed4111c840c8f)

Comment: What is the reason for using a custom xml processor. [Linq to Xml](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/mt693072.aspx) is very fast, reliable and really simple to use.

Comment: Writing a conformant XML parser is much harder than this, but it is a solved problem.  Don't reinvent the wheel; use an existing, proven XML parsing library.

Comment: @Nico because it isn't actually XML, just using the syntax type.  Here is the file I am reading: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/276558657/Asys/asys.txt  I found it easier to use regex because it is such a simple file

Comment: @kjhughes I never meant for it to be a full-fledged XML parser, just a way to easily get strings, which it does.  I just want to know why it doesn't work spanning across multiple lines. See what I am actually parsing in previous comment

Comment: @criticaldiamonds:  Then don't reference XML in your question or tagging.  XML means something very specific, not whatever you happen to feel like parsing.

Comment: @kjhughes got it. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RegEx is line oriented.

Since you already have something that works for single line input, consider cleaning up your input:

```
public static string Parse(string xml, string tag, bool clean, bool replaceNewLines)
{
   xml = xml.Replace("\r", "").Replace("\n", " ");
   ...

}
```

Comment: I see, I didn't realize that. Thanks.  I modified this slightly, replacing `\n` with `[-n]`, which is later converted back to `\n` after the result is determined.

Answer (score 2):

I have broken this down to its simplest form and that is by matching just the text inside the tag you are querying for.

Here is the example code:

```
const string TAG_REGEX_PATTERN = @"(?:<{0}>)([^<]+?)(?:<\/{0}>)";

public static string Parse(string xml, string tag, bool clean, bool replaceNewLines)
{
    if (xml == String.Empty || tag == String.Empty) { return "error"; }

    MatchCollection tagMatches = new Regex(string.Format(TAG_REGEX_PATTERN, tag), RegexOptions.Multiline | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Matches(xml);

    IList<string> tags = new List<string>();

    // Add the tag to a list
    foreach (Match m in tagMatches)
    {
        // Add the tag to the list
        tags.Add(m.Groups[1].Value);
        break; //break as only interested in first result.
    }

    string result = tags.Count == 0 ? null : tags[0];
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(result))
    {
        if (clean)
            result = result.Trim();
        if (replaceNewLines)
            result = result.Replace("\r\n", " ");
    }
    else
        result = "error";
    return result;
}
```

Now this will match the text inside the tag you are looking for and ignore the actual tags.

The regex is formatted directly using the tag in question (using `string.Format()`) and will result in a regex below.

```
(?:<test>)([^<]+?)(?:<\/test>)
```

Now I have left the loop in there in case you wish to return a value of all tags.

Comment: Thanks! Although i did end up using the other answer, this did give me some insight on how I might tackle this problem should I need to do something like this again. :)